# Polynomial Linear Regression,Where am i going wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, supervised-learning

I am doing a coursera assignment and here is the question:

> Write a function that fits a polynomial LinearRegression model on the training data X_train for degrees 0 through 9. For each model compute the  R2R2  (coefficient of determination) regression score on the training data as well as the the test data, and return both of these arrays in a tuple.
>
> This function should return one tuple of numpy arrays (r2_train,
>   r2_test). Both arrays should have shape (10,)

MY code:`
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score


np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)
def answer_two():

def answer_two():
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score

# Your code here


def r2_traintest(deg):  

    poly=PolynomialFeatures(deg)
    model=LinearRegression()
    X_f=poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1,1))

    a=model.fit(X_f,y_train)


    dee=a.predict(poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1,1)))

    deez=r2_score(dee,y_train)

    gin=a.predict(poly.transform(X_test.reshape(-1,1)))

    mint=r2_score(gin,y_test)

    return deez,mint


lst=[]
lsts=[]

for x in range(0,10,1):

    lst.append(r2_traintest(x)[0])

    lsts.append(r2_traintest(x)[1])


return (np.array(lst),np.array(lsts))
```

> unfortunately this is giving me a wrong answer,Am i missing something ,please help.

Comment: Can you provide a example of input and expected output ? For me the code looks fine but I'd write it in one function instead of 2 because it makes no sense to fit twice the model (in addition, you are doing a fit_transform in the test dataset (should be simply a transform usign the model fit in r2_trainscore)

Comment: Yeah,I've edited the question please look into it now.also I am new to coding so forgive me,I am amatuer at writing decent code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your are inverting args in the r2_score function. It has to be `r2_score(y_true, y_pred)`

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def fit_poly(deg):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(deg)
    model = LinearRegression()
    X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1, 1))
    model.fit(X_poly, y_train)

    y_pred_train = model.predict(poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1, 1)))
    r2_train = r2_score(y_train, y_pred_train)

    y_pred_test = model.predict(poly.transform(X_test.reshape(-1, 1)))
    r2_test = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_test)

    return r2_train, r2_test


np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

lst=[]
lsts=[]

for x in range(0,10,1):
    lst.append(fit_poly(x)[0])
    lsts.append(fit_poly(x)[1])

print(lst, lsts)
```

and results are :

> [0.0, 0.4292457781234663, 0.45109980444082465, 0.5871995368779847, 0.9194194471769304, 0.97578641430682, 0.9901823324795082, 0.9935250927840416, 0.996375453877599, 0.9980370625664945]
>
> [-0.4780864173714179, -0.45237104233936676, -0.0685698414991589, 0.005331052945740433, 0.7300494281871148, 0.8770830091614791, 0.9214093981415002, 0.9202150411139083, 0.6324795282222648, -0.645253216177847]

With your code, values were sometime above 1.

BTW, your new version of code is clearer, as you can see, I copy-pasted a lot of it :)

Comment: Ahh,now i see my amateur mistake ,thanks a lot,i want give an upvote but i got no reputation,sry.

Comment: @sajeera you can always make the answer as solution